# Displaying Outliers Using The any() function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe of five columns and 500 rows. The dataframe holds random integer values by executing the following Python code:

```
RandomValues = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(500, 5)), 
                 columns=['Name', 'State', 'Age', 'Experience', 'Annual Income'])
```

The following is the data frame:

```
    Name    State   Age Experience  Annual Income
 0    85       10    16         56             89
 1    94        1    87         61             37
 2    51        7    37         18             92
 3    15        1    62         72             60
 4    84       88     1         43             14

...  ...      ...   ...        ...            ...
495   66       33    67         84              7
496   81        2    55         87             59
497   38       50    40         77             36
498   68       45    37         55             90
499   13       82    84         98             35
```

I am using the standard deviation to find outliers in the "Annual Income" column.

```
upper_limit = RandomValues['Annual Income'].mean() + 3 * RandomValues['Annual Income'].std()
lower_limit = RandomValues['Annual Income'].mean() - 3 * RandomValues['Annual Income'].std()
```

How can I use the any() method to find the outliers on the "Annual Income" column of the "RandomValues" dataframe. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

I have tried to use the where() method, as well as the following Python code, but it did not solve the problem:
highOutliers = RandomValues['Annual Income'] < upper_limit
lowOutliers = RandomValues['Annual Income'] > lower_limit

print(highOutliers)
print(lowOutliers)

Secondly, I have attempted the following, but am getting back a Series with an empty list:

```
highOutliers = RandomValues.loc[RandomValues['Annual Income'] > upper_limit, 'Annual Income']
lowOutliers = RandomValues.loc[RandomValues['Annual Income'] < lower_limit, 'Annual Income']

print(highOutliers)
print(lowOutliers)

Output:
Series([], Name: Annual Income, dtype: int64)
Series([], Name: Annual Income, dtype: int64)
```

Comment: [please don't upload images of data/code/errors/etc](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). instead, copy the result of `print(df)` and paste it as a code block into your question. thank you!

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

When you just do a comparison like this, you're creating a `boolean` series, which is the same shape as your `Annual Income` column, but containing True/False values

```py
highOutliers_locations = RandomValues['Annual Income'] > upper_limit
lowOutliers_locations = RandomValues['Annual Income'] < lower_limit
```

This is a useful step in calculating the outliers, but you haven't subset the data yet.

To actually subset your dataframe to only include these outliers, use indexing, e.g with `.loc`:

```py
highOutliers = RandomValues.loc[highOutliers_locations, 'Annual Income']
lowOutliers = RandomValues.loc[lowOutliers_locations, 'Annual Income']
```

Or, in one step:

```py
highOutliers = RandomValues.loc[
    RandomValues['Annual Income'] > upper_limit, 'Annual Income'
]
lowOutliers = RandomValues.loc[
    RandomValues['Annual Income'] < lower_limit, 'Annual Income'
]
```

See the pandas guide to [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for more info and examples

Comment: It is odd that when I attempt this, it returns an empty list.

Comment: you might not have any outliers this many standard deviations from the mean... to help you debug any further we really need a [mre]. if you've randomly generated this data using code, that's great! please include that code in your question.

Comment: note that if you are using a uniform distribution, the standard deviation is `sqrt(1/12) * w` where w is the interval width. On a unit interval, that comes out to 0.289. 3x this is 0.86, which is more than half the interval. So for data sampled uniformly, I would not expect to get any "outliers" if you're defining them as being 3 standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: Thank you Michael Delgado. I have updated my post to show the source code I executed to generate the data frame with random values.

Comment: Thank you Michael Delgado. I have updated my question to include the Python source code I used to generate the data frame with random values.

Comment: Yeah so if you’re using randint, that’s a uniform distribution and you won’t get any values more than about 1.5 standard deviations from the mean. So the empty list is expected.

Comment: How could I fix this problem? What can I use instead of randint?

Comment: what problem? there's not necessarily a problem here as far as I can see. do you want outliers? if so, just use a smaller multiplier on the standard deviation. You could use a normal distribution if you'd like I suppose, but this isn't an issue with the code - you've filtered the data based on a condition which returns zero matches. you can change the condition or change the code, or just leave it as is - everything is working correctly as you've specified it :)

Comment: I would like to have outliers, but still use the same multiplier on the standard deviation. How can I generate a data frame that will accomplish this?

Comment: I was able to print the outliers with the any() function with the following code: Outliers = RandomValues[(np.abs(RandomValues) > (3*RandomValues.std())).any(1)]

Comment: this is `value > 3*std` not `value > mean + 3 * std` though